# Branch.io app install response

Tags: android, android-studio, branch.io

i am integrate branch.io referral reward sdk in my app.I found user can view reward and redeem from their database.Is it possible to store user credits in my database.

expecting after install I need to store credits in my database.
 Please some one help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the android database support https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/ if you want to use sql database check out https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite

Comment: Alesandro Giordano Thanks for the reply.IF my user installed a app from my referral link.Will My user APP get response after successful install.I couldnt find any response after successful Install.Please help me..

Comment: I've used mySql database in other way, if you want to follow this way too I can hel you

Comment: if you go better I can help you using a resource file as database

Comment: its a simple  and better way

Comment: No sorry, but I can send you a project using mysql db

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177369/discussion-between-selva-kumar-and-alesandro-giordano).

Comment: Ok, but please rate my answer when i’ll sent you the project

Comment: alessandrogiordano.assetx@gmail.com please write me